# How to create Menu By actionlinks in MVC4 Razor View?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

How to create menu in MVC4 Razor View by using ActionLikns ?

I am a very beginner in MVC so Please give me any example ?

Thanks in Advance

Ankur Tripathi

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how a very basic menu might look like:

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About us", "About", "Company")</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then you might want to apply some different CSS class to the *active* menu link. You could write a custom HTML helper then:

```
public static class MenuExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text, string action, string controller)
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
}
```

that could be used like this:

```
<ul>
    @Html.MenuItem("Home", "Index", "Home")
    @Html.MenuItem("About us", "About", "Company")
    ...
</ul>
```